# switch case difficulties - upon completion of the case statement I want php to carry out the commands past the break and out of the switch

Tags: php, view, include, switch-statement, case

I have this code:

```
function logout()
{
    $_SESSION = array(); //destroy all of the session variables
    session_destroy();
}

// defaults to welcome view unless a different view is requested
$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'welcome' : $_GET['view'];

switch ($view) {
    case "logout";
        logout();
        header('Location: index.php');
        break;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']) {
    include 'views/main/layout.php';
}
include 'views/main/loggedin.php';
```

What I want to happen is:

1. upon clicking logout (the case statement of logout runs).
2. the session contents are destroyed.
3. the user is redirected to the start of this page of code (index.php)
4. with the welcome view (as it is the default)
5. with the include statement including "layout.php", rather than "loggedin.php" which it was set to prior to clicking logout.

So it should be using layout as the template, with welcome in the main body.

However it is using loggedinlayout as the template, with welcome in the main body

So to fix this, I would need a way to somehow at the end of the logout case statement, redirect php to the end where it works out which layout to use.

Has anyone any suggestions? I was thinking of using GOTO commands.

Comment: `exit()` is missing after the `header()` call

Comment: Have you tried replacing `break;` with `exit;`?

Comment: Have tried these yes. When it goes to index.php from the header, it seems to ignore the include statements at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Your case condition should end with a colon, not semicolon:

```
 case "logout":
```

not

```
 case "logout";
```

Comment: Case condition can also be end with semicolon

Comment: Have fixed that, that doesn't fix the problem though.

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem - the include statements at the end were the wrong way round ! Thanks for the help all of you :)